# self join-SQL -Query

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

In an interview the below questions asked and couldn't provide an appropriate answer.

Question 1:
if i have a table with employee id and manager i want to display it in the below format with employee name and manager.( the employee id 1 have manager null. ***You need to use self join only***)

Question 2: if i have same result got for inner join ,right outer join and left outer join what type of content that table have?(i didnt get any sample data for this question. He asked me to assume)

[image]

Can anyone help me to find out answer for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question1: this is done with left join:

```
select t1.name, t2.name as manager
from tablename t1
left join tablename t2 on t1.manager = t2.id
```

Question2: Those tables can be empty for example, or contain same data on joined columns and same number of rows.

Comment: Can i use self join for this? There is no connection between question 1 and 2

Comment: When you are joining table on itself it is selfjoin. And yes you can do this.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, the answer to question 1 looks like this:

```
select emp.id,emp.name,emp.department,emp.salary,m.id as manager
from employee emp
left join employee m on m.id=emp.managerid
```

<strike>Not quite sure I understand the second question...</strike>

Answer to second question is that everyone has a manager (so no NULL values). In which case regardless of the types of join, the result will be the same.

Comment: I got O/P using left join but unable to query using self join. also for question please dont take the table structure as a reference.  If all the joins gave the same result what type of data that table contains?

Comment: Err...it is a self join, the table joins on itself.